# Why my Swift app throws a fatal error when I try to unwrap the optional?

Tags: arrays, swift, filtering

I have an array (it is optional) which I try to filter. Inside of that array there are instances of some custom struct. They have a `distance` property which is a `String`. Now, the condition for filtering the array is that these strings should be less than or equal to some float value (`distance`). Here is the code:

```
filteredUnitRestaurants = anotherUnitRestaurant?.filter({ (restaurant) -> Bool in
    print (restaurant.distance)
    return Float(restaurant.distance)! <= Float(distance)
})
```

When I implement it, Xcode throws an error, which says that it unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (in the line of a boolean expression). However, the `print` method prints the `distance` value, so it is not nil, but when I change the print statement like this:

```
print (Float(restaurant.distance)!)
```

It throws an error, too. So, I think the problem is related to converting the string value to float, but the value of `distance` is just a number. When I print it on the console, it looks like this:   `Optional(10999.795970332603)`

So, I don't know what could make Xcode complain. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: How are you setting `restaurant.distance`?  The "Optional(" is probably part of the string so it can't create a Float from it

Comment: @dan, yes you are right. I get it by finding the distance between two locations. To save it, I change its type to String, but String's  initialiser adds that "Optional(" thing in front of numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `restaurant.distance` was an optional string, the compiler would have thrown an error that a Float cannot be formed with the type `String?` because you aren't unwrapping `restaurant.distance` in `Float(restaurant.distance)!`. But it did not which makes me think that the string itself is getting stored as `Optional(10999.795970332603)` like dan pointed out in the comments to your question. Change that to hold a valid number which passes conversion to `Float`. You'll lose precision like Paulw11 pointed out but at least it won't crash. And try using `if let` instead of force unwrapping to avoid crashing when found nil.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  I get `distance` by finding the distance between two locations. To save it, I change its type to String, but String's  initialiser adds that "Optional(" thing in front of numbers. Maybe that's String's new initialiser `init(describing:)`, because I get distance from `distance(from:)` method?

Answer (score 2):

Essentially you are getting a crash because you *told Swift to crash* if something was `nil` by force unwrapping with `!`.

Why you are getting `nil` I can't say, as that value can be converted to a `Float` successfully; perhaps it is crashing on some other bit of data, or perhaps the string is literally `Optional(10999.795970332603)` - in which case you have a problem somewhere else where you are creating that string value without correctly unwrapping a value.

Assuming that `restaurant.distance` is actually an optional String (ie. `String?`) not a String that contains `Optional(10999.795970332603)` you should code defensively and use conditional unwrapping.

You may also want to use `Double` instead of `Float`.  A `Float` is only 32 bits and you are losing a lot of precision; 10999.795970332603 as a `Float` is 10999.8 while as a `Double` it is 10999.7959703326.

Finally, convert `distance` to a `Double` before you filter; you are doing unnecessary work converting it each time

```
let doubleDistance = Double(distance)
filteredUnitRestaurants = anotherUnitRestaurant?.filter({ (restaurant) -> Bool in
    guard let distanceStr = restaurant.distance, 
          let restaurantDistance = Double(distanceStr) else {
              return false
    }
    return restaurantDistance <= doubleDistance
 })
```